# Privacy when signing in with Google

Tags: google-plus, google-account, privacy, openid

Lately many websites allow users to sign in using their Google accounts, which seems to be fine, but I am a bit worried about privacy issues...

I have been taking a look, and most of the information I got is about how Google protects your privacy from the sites you sign in, which is indeed very important...

But my question is about the other way around, I mean, when you sign in with Google in a site, what can Google know about that? Obviously it can know that you have an account in there, but can it access any other data about your account in the site?

Answer (score 1):

Signing into a third-party service with your Google account **usually does give Google services access to activity on that account.** This is useful to the end user mostly on social services by allowing you to easily share activity on Google+.

By default, your posted activity in apps you've signed into with Google is **visible to everyone in your circles** on G+. Information gathered from these apps is also used by Google ad services and in personalized search, both in building your personal ad/search profile, and while serving ads and search results to people in your circles.

However, you should note that individual apps have specific policies on how your data is shared, and you should probably **consult the app's privacy policy** if looking for a specific case. [Here is a link](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2980762?hl=en) with some of Google's official documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a lot of info when you use Google services
[google dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/?hl=it%E2%80%8E)

Google knows a lot of you, but it offers a lot of services.
It is hard to decide how deep you can offer your data, it is a personal choice...

I hope that link can helps you

Comment: I think he was referring to third-party apps which allow you to authenticate with a Google account, not Google's own services.